# Facebook SDK iOS app stay logged in when app quits

Tags: ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

Currently I'm using the below if statement to check if the user has an open session to facebook through my app.

```
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
     // post to wall
}
else {
     [appDelegate openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:YES];
}
```

If the user quits the app then the session is closed and my if statement opens a new session, however I would like to keep the session open even if the user quits the app.

I tried removing `[FBSession.activeSession close]` from `applicationWillTerminate:` however this didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can't logout fully. but you can clear all detail of last session by below code.

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

you can write it according to your requirement either in applicationDidEnterBackground or applicationWillTerminate.

Thanks